# Remainder of $2^y$ and $3^y$

Tags: number-theory

When is $$2^y\mod  3^x = 1$$

where $x,y\geq0$ and $x,y$ are integers.
I know the trivial solutions but can anyone please provide non-trivial solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: how do you do >= in Tex?

Comment: Please try to avoid double `$$` in titles. `\geq` yields $\geq$, and `\leq` yields $\leq$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Sorry about the title.

Comment: Use a \geq for greater than/equal to and \leq for less than/equal to.

Comment: Or \ge and \le.

Comment: What are the trivial solutions? $y=0$; $x=1,2|y$; $x=2, 6|y$; and in general $2\cdot 3^{x-1}|y$?

Comment: @Hagen: aren't those all solutions?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I don't know. These are all I know, but Euler is a oneway street.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\ge 2$. Then since $2$ is a primitive root of $3^2$, it is a primitive root of $3^x$. It follows that $2$ has order $\varphi(3^x)=2\cdot 3^{x-1}$ modulo $3^x$. 
(One can prove the order result with less machinery.)

Thus the "trivial" Euler's Theorem solutions are the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if you consider this not trivial, but by [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), and the fact that $\phi(3^x)=2\cdot3^{x-1}$, you get the set of solutions $(x,k\cdot2\cdot3^{x-1})$ for any $k,x$ positive integers

Comment: I do not see a question. This seems a bit chatty or such.
Seems like a case of ' not a real question '.